# How to properly use in the implementation of IMFByteStream

Tags: c++, video, ms-media-foundation

I try to play an "encrypted" movie for a quick implementation (in terms of performance) I prefer to go with Microsoft Media Foundation.

The point is that for the purpose of playing an encrypted movie I need to perform some actions on the movie before reading or writing to it, and Windows specifically created for this function the BeginCreateObjectFromByteStream, which aims to produce me a media source from ByteStream.

For me to use this function I have to implement my own IMFByteStream that could read and write to the encrypted file.

This is what I tried to do:

Here is the code for my IMFByteStream object:

```
#pragma once
#include <Mfidl.h>

#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex

#define FILE_NAME ("C:\\try_file.mp4")



class my_IMFByteStream : public IMFByteStream
{


public:
    my_IMFByteStream()
    {
        file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r+");

        // init our end position
        end_position = -1;

        // init referance counter
        reference_counter = 1;
    };


    virtual ~my_IMFByteStream() {

    };

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Close()
    {
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    };


    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetCapabilities(DWORD *pdwCapabilities)
    {
        *pdwCapabilities = MFBYTESTREAM_IS_READABLE | MFBYTESTREAM_IS_WRITABLE | MFBYTESTREAM_IS_SEEKABLE;
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Read(BYTE  *pb, ULONG cb, ULONG *pcbRead)
    {
        *pcbRead = fread(pb, 1, cb, file);

        /* copy and decrypt */
        for (ULONG i = 0; i < *pcbRead; i++)
        {
            pb[i] ^= 0x55;
        }


        return S_OK;
    }


    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Write(const BYTE  *pb, ULONG cb, ULONG *pcbWritten)
    {
        BYTE * n_pb = new BYTE[cb];
        for (ULONG i = 0; i < cb; i++)
        {
            n_pb[i] = pb[i] ^ 0x55;
        }

        *pcbWritten = fwrite(n_pb, 1, cb, file);


        delete[] n_pb;


        return S_OK;
    }


    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Flush()
    {
        return fflush(file);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetCurrentPosition(QWORD qwPosition)
    {
        //qwPosition[in] == New position in the stream, as a byte offset from the start of the stream.
        return fseek(file, qwPosition, SEEK_SET);
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetCurrentPosition(QWORD *pqwPosition)
    {
        *pqwPosition = ftell(file);
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE BeginRead( BYTE     *pb,   ULONG     cb,   IMFAsyncCallback *pCallback,    IUnknown     *punkState)
    {
        // must be implemented with a thread 
        std::thread([=] { inner_async_read(pb, cb, pCallback, punkState); });       
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE BeginWrite(const BYTE  *pb,     ULONG     cb,     IMFAsyncCallback *pCallback,    IUnknown    *punkState)
    {
        // must be implemented with a thread 
        std::thread([=] { inner_async_write(pb, cb, pCallback, punkState); });
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetLength( QWORD *pqwLength)
    {

        // save current position
        long int curr_loc = ftell(file);

        // return file length
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        *pqwLength = ftell(file);

        // restore to curr location
        fseek(file, curr_loc, SEEK_SET);

        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Seek(  MFBYTESTREAM_SEEK_ORIGIN SeekOrigin,     LONGLONG    qwSeekOffset,  DWORD    dwSeekFlags,   QWORD   *pqwCurrentPosition    )
    {
        // not sure what to do with seek flags ....
        switch (SeekOrigin)
        {
        case msoBegin:
        {
            //The seek position is specified relative to the start of the stream.
            fseek(file, qwSeekOffset, SEEK_SET);
            break;
        }
        case msoCurrent:
        {
            //The seek position is specified relative to the current read/write position in the stream.
            fseek(file, qwSeekOffset, SEEK_CUR);
            break;
        }
        }

        *pqwCurrentPosition = ftell(file);

        return S_OK;
    }


    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsEndOfStream(BOOL *pfEndOfStream)
    {
        if (-1 == end_position)
        {
            // init to the real end position

            // save current position
            long int curr_loc = ftell(file);

            // return file length
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
            end_position = ftell(file);

            // restore to curr location
            fseek(file, curr_loc, SEEK_SET);
        }

        if (ftell(file) == end_position)
        {
            *pfEndOfStream = true;
        }
        else
        {
            *pfEndOfStream = false;
        }

        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EndRead( IMFAsyncResult *pResult,  ULONG  *pcbRead)
    {
        *pcbRead = actual_read;
        pResult->SetStatus(S_OK);

        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EndWrite( IMFAsyncResult *pResult, ULONG    *pcbWritten)
    {
        *pcbWritten = actual_read;
        pResult->SetStatus(S_OK);

        return S_OK;
    }


    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetLength( QWORD qwLength)
    {
        QWORD curr_length = 0;
        GetLength(&curr_length);

        if (curr_length > qwLength)
        {
            // can't shrink a file
            return E_FAIL;
        }
        if (curr_length == qwLength)
        {
            // there is nothing to do 
            return S_OK;
        }

        // use lock 
        mtx.lock();

        fseek(file, qwLength, SEEK_SET);
        ULONG garbage = 0;
        const BYTE nada[1] = { "" };
        Write(nada, 1, &garbage);

        // free lock
        mtx.unlock();
        return S_OK;
    }



    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release()
    {
        if (reference_counter == 0)
        {
            delete this;
            return 0;
        }

        reference_counter--;
        return reference_counter;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
    {
        // no idea what this code douse ...
        static const QITAB qit[] =
        {
            QITABENT(my_IMFByteStream, IMFByteStream),
            { 0 }
        };
        return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef()
    {
        reference_counter++;
        return reference_counter;
    }

protected:
    void inner_async_write( const BYTE  *pb,     ULONG     cb,      IMFAsyncCallback *pCallback,   IUnknown    *punkState)
    {
        // use lock 
        mtx.lock();

        // make the actual write
        actual_write = 0;
        Write(pb, cb, &actual_write);

        // set the results
        ULONG pcbUnclear = 0;
        if (punkState != NULL)
        {
            EndWrite((IMFAsyncResult *)punkState, &pcbUnclear);
        }


        // free lock
        mtx.unlock();

        // call callback "we done"
        pCallback->Invoke((IMFAsyncResult *)punkState);
    }

    void inner_async_read( BYTE  *pb, ULONG  cb, IMFAsyncCallback *pCallback,    IUnknown         *punkState)
    {
        // use lock 
        mtx.lock();

        // make the actual read
        actual_read = 0;
        Read(pb, cb, &actual_read);

        // set the results
        ULONG pcbUnclear = 0;
        if (punkState != NULL)
        {
            EndRead((IMFAsyncResult *)punkState, &pcbUnclear);
        }


        // free lock
        mtx.unlock();

        // call callback "we done"
        pCallback->Invoke((IMFAsyncResult *)punkState);
    }


private:
    FILE* file;
    std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

    long int end_position;
    ULONG actual_read;
    ULONG actual_write;
    ULONG reference_counter;
};
```

Here's how I try to use the object:

```
HRESULT CreateMediaSource(PCWSTR sURL, IMFMediaSource **ppSource, CPlayer * our_impl)
{
    MF_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;

    IMFSourceResolver* pSourceResolver = NULL;
    IUnknown* pSource = NULL;

    // Create the source resolver.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSourceResolver(&pSourceResolver);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Use the source resolver to create the media source.

    // -> Create my object
    my_IMFByteStream * bytesrc = new my_IMFByteStream();

    // -> Try to use it as my new source instead of the default msdn implementation that commented bellow
    hr = pSourceResolver->BeginCreateObjectFromByteStream(bytesrc, NULL, MF_RESOLUTION_READ, NULL, NULL, our_impl, pSource); // in this line i get exception "Unhandled exception at 0x013C1169"

    //hr = pSourceResolver->CreateObjectFromURL(
    //  sURL,                       // URL of the source.
    //  MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE,  // Create a source object.
    //  NULL,                       // Optional property store.
    //  &ObjectType,        // Receives the created object type. 
    //  &pSource            // Receives a pointer to the media source.
    //);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the IMFMediaSource interface from the media source.
    hr = pSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(ppSource));

done:
    SafeRelease(&pSourceResolver);
    SafeRelease(&pSource);
    return hr;
}
```

I get experience when I try to run this code and it is not so clear to me why, is there anyone here who has more experience with things from this style and can direct me where I am wrong?

p.s. This is the implementation of MSDN to CPlayer (I am at this stage trying to make small changes on this basis to isolate errors to the section I added - I rely on the rest of the code written by Microsoft is accurate)

```
template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}

const UINT WM_APP_PLAYER_EVENT = WM_APP + 1;

// WPARAM = IMFMediaEvent*, WPARAM = MediaEventType

enum PlayerState
{
    Closed = 0,     // No session.
    Ready,          // Session was created, ready to open a file. 
    OpenPending,    // Session is opening a file.
    Started,        // Session is playing a file.
    Paused,         // Session is paused.
    Stopped,        // Session is stopped (ready to play). 
    Closing         // Application has closed the session, but is waiting for MESessionClosed.
};

class CPlayer : public IMFAsyncCallback
{
public:
    static HRESULT CreateInstance(HWND hVideo, HWND hEvent, CPlayer **ppPlayer);

    // IUnknown methods
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv);
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef();
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release();

    // IMFAsyncCallback methods
    STDMETHODIMP  GetParameters(DWORD*, DWORD*)
    {
        // Implementation of this method is optional.
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP  Invoke(IMFAsyncResult* pAsyncResult);

    // Playback
    HRESULT       OpenURL(const WCHAR *sURL);
    HRESULT       Play();
    HRESULT       Pause();
    HRESULT       Stop();
    HRESULT       Shutdown();
    HRESULT       HandleEvent(UINT_PTR pUnkPtr);
    PlayerState   GetState() const { return m_state; }

    // Video functionality
    HRESULT       Repaint();
    HRESULT       ResizeVideo(WORD width, WORD height);

    BOOL          HasVideo() const { return (m_pVideoDisplay != NULL); }

protected:

    // Constructor is private. Use static CreateInstance method to instantiate.
    CPlayer(HWND hVideo, HWND hEvent);

    // Destructor is private. Caller should call Release.
    virtual ~CPlayer();

    HRESULT Initialize();
    HRESULT CreateSession();
    HRESULT CloseSession();
    HRESULT StartPlayback();

    // Media event handlers
    virtual HRESULT OnTopologyStatus(IMFMediaEvent *pEvent);
    virtual HRESULT OnPresentationEnded(IMFMediaEvent *pEvent);
    virtual HRESULT OnNewPresentation(IMFMediaEvent *pEvent);

    // Override to handle additional session events.
    virtual HRESULT OnSessionEvent(IMFMediaEvent*, MediaEventType)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

protected:
    long                    m_nRefCount;        // Reference count.

    IMFMediaSession         *m_pSession;
    IMFMediaSource          *m_pSource;
    IMFVideoDisplayControl  *m_pVideoDisplay;

    HWND                    m_hwndVideo;        // Video window.
    HWND                    m_hwndEvent;        // App window to receive events.
    PlayerState             m_state;            // Current state of the media session.
    HANDLE                  m_hCloseEvent;      // Event to wait on while closing.
};
```

Comment: i know not very helpful, but i can only recommend to dump the idea of using directshow/media foundation and instead use libavcodec.

Comment: Thank you but currently i prefer using the native options.

Comment: Reading the ms docs of the async method BeginCreate... on MSDN, the last argument is *punkState but from your code i see you pass in **IMFMediaSource. The arguments you are passing seems to match more the synch method CreateObjectFromByteStream method. (just a shot in the dark, as nobody else is answerring)

Answer (score 0):

So your movie is encrypted.

So you have to decrypt the "ByteStream" inside your IMFByteStream implementation.

If you return encrypted "ByteStream" like you do here, who will decrypt it ?

Mediafoundation does not provides such things, nor does your IMFByteStream implementation. And SourceResolver is not able to handle a crypted "ByteStream" (Except the fact that a MediaFoundation Source is able to do it, but, by default, it does not exist, as far as i know).

You just have have to add decryption inside IMFByteStream implementation, and return decrypted "ByteStream".

That said, what is the encryption file type ? (DRM ? whole file (zip) ? etc... ?), the answer may be different.